# It's a question on an english phrase in a sentence

Tags: paraphrasing

> What distinguishes Keynesians from other economists is their belief in activist policy to reduce the amplitude of the business cycle.
>
> Rather than seeing unbalanced government budgets as wrong, Keynes advocated so called that act against the direction if the business cycle.

These two paragraphs are from the economics article that I've been reading recently, and I'm not sure about the meaning of 'so called that act' in this context. From what I understood, this phrase is a paraphrasing of 'unbalanced government budgets', but I'm not sure if I'm getting it right. Can someone please explain how this phrase is used in this context?

Comment: This is misquoted.

Comment: Looks like a typo.

Answer (score 3):

It's a typo:

> No policy prescriptions follow from these three tenets alone. What
> distinguishes Keynesians from other economists is their belief in
> activist policies to reduce the amplitude of the business cycle, which
> they rank among the most important of all economic problems.
>
> Rather than seeing unbalanced government budgets as wrong, Keynes
> advocated so-called **countercyclical fiscal policies** that act against
> the direction of the business cycle.

https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/fandd/2014/09/basics.htm

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand why the text was difficult to comprehend.